# How can I add a relationship in Django to a model that's created before the model I need to reference?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two different models: Movies and Characters. I want Characters to have a movies field where I can see the movies in which the characters appear and I want Movies to have the characters that appear in them. However, since one of the models has to be defined first, I am not sure how to make the first one relate to the second one.

This is my code so far but this doesn't show 'movies' when I access the Character model:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    story = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character) 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am not sure how to add the movies to the Character model since it's referenced before the Movie model, how can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did. If you define a relation from model *A* to model *B*, then Django will also define an extra relation from *B* to *A*. You can here obtain the `Movie`s where a `Character` plays a role with:

```
my_character.movie_set.all()
```

If you want to change that name, for example to `movies`, you can use the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) to specify the name of the relation in reverse:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(
        Character,
        related_name='movies'
    )
```

Then you thus query with:

```
my_character.movies.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

When defining a related field, just wrap the model name in quotes:

```py
characters = models.ManyToManyField('Character')
```

However, you don't need to define the relationship on both table.  You can add a related_name:

```py
class Movie(models.Model):
    ...
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character, related_name='movies')
```

This will make `movies` available on any Character model
This will make `movies` available on